# yii2: how to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin header

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have this yii2 controller where I want to set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header

```
class DoctorController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'api\modules\v1\models\Doctor';

    public function behaviors()
    {

        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();



        $behaviors['access'] = [
            'class' => \yii\filters\AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    // All actions
                    'allow' => true,
                    'actions' => ['index', 'view'],
                ],
            ],
        ];

        return $behaviors;
    }
}
```

#### Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have solved it by updating the behaviors() function**

```
    public function behaviors()
    {

        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();

        $behaviors['corsFilter'] = [
            'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
            'cors' => [
                'Origin' => ['*'],
                'Access-Control-Request-Method' => ['GET'], // add more 
                'Access-Control-Request-Headers' => ['*'],
                'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => null,
                'Access-Control-Max-Age' => 86400,
            ],
        ];

        $behaviors['access'] = [
            'class' => \yii\filters\AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    // All actions
                    'allow' => true,
                    'actions' => ['index', 'view'], // add more
                ],
            ],
        ];

        return $behaviors;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this simple code:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

It may be added into one of your controller's `action` or into `beforeAction()` of your Controller or other use case (at your discretion according to the logic/architecture of your application).
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-controller#beforeAction()-detail